# Microsoft Graph API - Sites not found using search - how can i find all the sites?

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api

Was not able to find a way to discover all the sites of an organization:

- creating a site with user2
- approving the app with an admin
- using 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=' does not show the new site.

Only once i add the admin to the site group I find the new site.

how can I find all the sites?

Do I need to get an access token for each user?

For example with this token I can access all the drives but can't find the sites.

Comment: Improved question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things going on related to what you're asking and I'll try to address each of them:

1) We don't have an officially supported way to discover all of the sites and site collections in a given tenant today.  The "search=*" query may give you the results you're after but it is not guaranteed in all scenarios.  We're looking at this scenario but do not have formal support in the product today.

2) Search results are security trimmed, when using delegated permissions the search API will only return sites that the logged in user has access to.  This could explain why you needed to add the Admin first before it showed up.

3) To use search in scenarios where you do not want security trimmed results you will need to user Application permissions and have the Tenant Admin perform the application consent flow for the entire tenant.  This is a fairly broad permission but is required for some scenarios.

Comment: "3).... to user Application permissions and have the Tenant Admin perform the application consent flow for the entire tenant...."
is this feasible for a tenant with 15k users?


we found a workaround
but i prefer we work as Microsoft wanted us to work.
we're trying to scan all tenant drives (including OneDrive and Sharepoint)
and all tenant sites.